# How to create multiple jagged arrays in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am working on a project where i get data from the service which is nested four levels deep and i want to recreate the data. I want to only have objects with state name = accepted. The state names differ and there can be multiple subcategories in a category the same is true for sub-subcategories. Thus i need to create something like this :

```
Category =  {

     Key = 1;
     Name = Cars;

     subCategories =     (

                {

                   Key = 4;
                   Name  = “SUV";

                   subSubCategories =             (

                                {

                                     Key = 13;
                                     Name = “7 Seater";

                                     state =         (

                                            {

                                            Key = 8;
                                            Name = Accepted;

                    }

                );

            }

        );

    },
```

Currently i am using 4 for loops to go into the object 4 levels deep and check where the 
`[state[i] objectForKey : @"Key"]isEqual: @8]`.
 My issues comes when i try to recreate the object with its proper mappings of **category->subcategory->sub-subcategory->state**. How can i recreate this object using NSMuttableArrays.

This is my code :

```
    for (int i =0; i < categories.count; i++) {


        NSArray* subCategories= [categories[i] objectForKey: @"subCategories"];

            for (int j = 0; j < subCategories.count; j++){

                NSArray* subCategoriesA =[subCategories[j] objectForKey:@"subSubCategories"];


                    for (int k = 0; k < subSubCategoriesA.count; k++){

                        NSArray* stateA =[subSubCategories[k] objectForKey:@"state"];


                            for (int u = 0; u < state.count; u++){

                                if ( [[stateA[u] objectForKey:@"Key"]  isEqual: @8] ) {



                                // recreate category->subcategory->sub-subcategory->state  based on this condition being fulfilled


                                }

                            }

                       }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Create a model.

Comment: Using model class is the best way...https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle try this

Comment: how do i do that without using a library do u mind showing me a simple example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model Approach**

i am using swift so my answer in swift language

As per your json you need to create these classes

**1,DataInfo**

```
class DataInfo : NSObject {
    var key : Int!
    var Name : String!

    override init() {
        key = 0
        Name = ""
    }

    init(withInfo : [String : Any]) {
        key = withInfo["Key"] as? Int ?? 0
        Name = withInfo["Name"] as? String ?? ""
        super.init()
    }
}
```

**2.SubSubCategories**

```
class SubSubCategories : NSObject {
    var key : Int!
    var name : String!
    var state : [DataInfo] = []

    override init() {
        key = 0
        name = ""

    }

    init(withInfo : [String : Any]) {
        key = withInfo["Key"] as? Int ?? 0
        name = withInfo["Name"] as? String ?? ""

        if let stateDict = withInfo["state"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            for dict in stateDict {
                let stateObj = DataInfo(withInfo: dict)
                state.append(stateObj)
            }
        }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

**3.SubCategories**

```
class SubCategories : NSObject {
    var key : Int!
    var name : String!
    var subSubCategories : [SubSubCategories] = []

    override init() {
        key = 0
        name = ""

    }

    init(withInfo : [String : Any]) {
        key = withInfo["Key"] as? Int ?? 0
        name = withInfo["Name"] as? String ?? ""

        if let subSubCategoriesDict = withInfo["subSubCategories"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            for dict in subSubCategoriesDict {
                let subSubCategoriesObj = SubSubCategories(withInfo: dict)
                subSubCategories.append(subSubCategoriesObj)
            }
        }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

**4.Category**

```
class Category : NSObject {
    var key : Int!
    var name : String!
    var subCategories : [SubCategories] = []

    override init() {
        key = 0
        name = ""

    }

    init(withInfo : [String : Any]) {
        key = withInfo["Key"] as? Int ?? 0
        name = withInfo["Name"] as? String ?? ""

        if let subCategoriesDict = withInfo["subCategories"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            for dict in subCategoriesDict {
                let subCategoriesObj = SubCategories(withInfo: dict)
                subCategories.append(subCategoriesObj)
            }
        }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Now All require model classes are created.now when you get response from server, list of Category you just fill the array of Category like this way.

```
var arrayCategory : [Category] = []

for categoriesDict in categories {
    let objCategorie = Category(withInfo: categoriesDict)
    arrayCategory.append(objCategorie)
}
```

Now you can fire Predicate on `arrayCategory` to get state object key == 8 
How to fire predicate on array is a different question. Or also you can filter `arrayCategory` where state object key == 8

**Edit**
For Objective C

**DataInfo**
**DataInfo.h**

```
@interface DataInfo : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) withInfo;
@end
```

**DataInfo.m**

```
#import "DataInfo.h"

@implementation DataInfo

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _key = 0;
        _name = @"";
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)withInfo {
        self = [super init];
        if(!self)
            return nil;

        _key = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Key"];
        _name = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Name"];

        return self;
    }

@end
```

**SubSubCategories.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SubSubCategories : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *state;

-(id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) withInfo;
@end
```

**SubSubCategories.m**

```
#import "SubSubCategories.h"
#import "DataInfo.h"

@implementation SubSubCategories

- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)withInfo {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self)
    return nil;

    self.key = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Key"];
    self.name = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Name"];
    self.state = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arry = (NSArray *)[withInfo valueForKey:@"state"];
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < arry.count; j++) {
        DataInfo *obj = [[DataInfo alloc] initWithInfo:arry[j]];
        [self.state addObject:obj];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**SubCategories.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SubCategories : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subSubCategories;

-(id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) withInfo;
@end
```

**SubCategories.m**

```
#import "SubCategories.h"
#import "SubSubCategories.h"

@implementation SubCategories

- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)withInfo {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self)
    return nil;

    self.key = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Key"];
    self.name = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Name"];
    self.subSubCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arry = (NSArray *)[withInfo valueForKey:@"subSubCategories"];
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < arry.count; j++) {
        SubSubCategories *obj = [[SubSubCategories alloc] initWithInfo:arry[j]];
        [self.subSubCategories addObject:obj];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Category.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Category : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subCategories;

-(id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) withInfo;
@end
```

**Category.m**

```
#import "Category.h"
#import "SubCategories.h"

@implementation Category
- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)withInfo {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self)
    return nil;

    self.key = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Key"];
    self.name = [withInfo valueForKey:@"Name"];
    self.subCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arry = (NSArray *)[withInfo valueForKey:@"subSubCategories"];
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < arry.count; j++) {
        SubCategories *obj = [[SubCategories alloc] initWithInfo:arry[j]];
        [self.subCategories addObject:obj];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer however i have no knowledge of swift, its kind of hard for me to follow what is going on in your answer